# Have a child window be notified when parent window goes to a different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a parent window and a child window. in javascript, i want a function in child window to be called whenever the parent window loads a new page. i'd like to use something similar to jQuery's $(document).ready() so that I don't have to worry about whether the parent is done loading yet - but ready() only appears to fire when the window loads the *first* page - but not when, say, a link is clicked in the parent and it loads a *second* page.

any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the parent window's `unload` event.